# Can not submit a form with robobrowser. Invalid submit error

Tags: python-3.x, request, beautifulsoup, robobrowser

Here is my code:
        from robobrowser import browser

```
    url = 'http://diesel.elcat.kg/index.php?act=Login&CODE=00'
    url3 = 'http://diesel.elcat.kg/index.php?act=post&do=reply_post&f=178&t=233500064'
    m = browser.RoboBrowser()
    m.open(url)
    # SIGNING IN(form1)
    form1 = m.get_form(action='https://diesel.elcat.kg/index.php?act=Login&CODE=01')
    form1['UserName'].value = 'Username'
    form1['PassWord'].value = 'Password'
    m.submit_form(form1)
    # FINISHED SIGNING IN(everything worked)
    # GOING TO THE PAGE WHERE FORM IS LOCATED
    m.open(url3)
    # Can't submit this form
    form2 = m.get_form(action="http://diesel.elcat.kg/index.php?")
    form2['Post'].value = 'up'
    m.submit_form(form2)
```

I can sign in to the website so form1 works, but when I try in this case leave a comment(up), form2 does not work.I am keep getting either InvalidSubmit error either Bad Request error. Code of form1 and code of form2 seem to be the same, but one works and another does not. I am using python3.5 and robobrowser, and I am using Mac OS if that's gonna help. Thank you in advance. 
Here is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/bkkadmin/Desktop/Daniiar/upper/test2.py", line 18, in <module>
 m.submit_form(form)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/robobrowser-0.5.3-py3.5.egg/robobrowser/browser.py", line 339, in submit_form
 payload = form.serialize(submit=submit)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/robobrowser-0.5.3-py3.5.egg/robobrowser/forms/form.py", line 226, in serialize
 include_fields = prepare_fields(self.fields, self.submit_fields, submit)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/robobrowser-0.5.3-py3.5.egg/robobrowser/forms/form.py", line 154, in prepare_fields
 raise exceptions.InvalidSubmitError()
robobrowser.exceptions.InvalidSubmitError
```

Answer (score 7):

I experienced the same issue today, with the same exact errors. One possible cause of the above issue is that your form2 actually contains more than one submit field, corresponding to more than one submit button in the original html. You can check this by `print(len(list(form2.submit_fields.items(multi=True))))`. If this is the case, your call to `submit_form` has to be modified as `m.submit_form(form2, submit=your_submit)`, where the second  argument `your_submit` is the relevant submit field you want to use. This [reference](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/issues/22) discusses how to extract the submit field you desire.

Incidentally, if you wonder where the long `print` code comes from, it comes from the body of `prepare_fields` in robobrowser/forms/form.py, which is indicated in one of the error outputs you posted.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It happens when the package you installed courrupted in your current project...
So try to create a new project in pycharm. And install robobrowser library again....
And paste your file in new project...

Note**use this method only if your code is completely correct**

Comment: This can be a great comment but not an answer. Read the rules, please.